# php - regex to get contents in DIV tags

Tags: php, html

Hello and thank for looking at my question. 
I'm in need to grab some data from an HTML snippet.
This source is a trusted/structured one so I think it's OK to use regex in this HTML. Dom and other advanced features in php are an overkill I guess.

Here is the format of the HTML snippet.

```
<div id="d-container">
  <div id="row-custom_1">
     <div class="label">Type</div>
     <div class="content">John Smith</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In above, please note the first 2 DIV tags have IDs set. There could be several row-custom_1 like div tags so I will need to escape them.

I'm actually very poor in regex so I'm expecting a help from you to rab the John Smith from above html snippet.

It could be something like

```
<div * id="row-custom_1" * > * <div * class="content" * >GRAB THIS </div>
```

but I don't know how to do it in regex. 
John Smith part won't contain any html for sure. it's from a trusted source that it strips all html and gives the data in above format.

I can understand that regex is never a good idea to process HTML anyway.
Thank you very much for any assistance.

Edit just after 30 minutes: 
Many of the awesome people suggested to use an HTML parser so I did ; worked like a charm. So if anyone comes here with a similar question, as the stupid question author, I'd recommend using DOM for the job.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: @Truth: Yes, and I agree. I have read many questions here before asking this and realized that what I'm going to do is wrong. 
But I'm much curious about using a html parser here. I'm trying to get the user's name to set the HTML title of the page so firing some dom stuff on each page load is not a very good idea either. The html structure is sure to be same. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Even though your source is "trusted", you should still check that it is valid. Use an HTML parser

Comment: The scaremongering notwithstanding, this isn't a task where manual regex matching is sensible. One could use a recursive match to find the correct snippet; but that does require more expertise; and so a DOM traversal library might not be that much slower. Querypath `qp($html)->find("#d-container, #row-custom_1, .content")->text()` is shorter for sure - though the invalid IDs might screw it.

Comment: @joeframbach Thanks! I tried using php5 SimpleXML but I'm getting even confused. Both Regex and simplexml have a rough learning curve :( 
I was thinking as the html is actually a structured one, regex would be easier and friendly with memory.

Comment: Memory is a concern for this? Is your server a Commodore 64?

Comment: @mario What's invalid about those IDs?

Comment: @joeframbach IDs may not contain hyphens. Only class names can.

Comment: @Mario thanks a lot for the query path!

Comment: @mario hyphens are valid? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Comment: @joeframbach Thanks. I only knew about the recent html5 relaxation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple DOM based code to get your value from the given HTML:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<div id="d-container">
  <div id="row-custom_1">
     <div class="label">Type</div>
     <div class="content">John Smith</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$value = $xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@id='d-container']
         /div[@id='row-custom_1']/div[@class='content']/text())"); 
echo "User Name: [$value]\n"; // prints your user name
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
User Name: [John Smith]
```

Comment: OMG that worked like a charm, @anubhava !!!
Thank you very very much!

Never use regex for HTML!
I wish I can use the vote up button before getting 15 rep here.

Comment: Welcome to SO community. Even if I can stop even one person for using regex to parse HTML, I would think that is worth spending my 5 minutes to provide this answer. Also I think you've got more than 15 reps from your question now :)